# PHP - How to capture only one string between delimiters from multiline strings based on defined position

Tags: php, regex, delimiter, multiline

I have a little web sql editor but when user writes a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT * FROM references;|  <-- here is the caret, i want to run only this query
SELECT * FROM settings
```

and submit that string, only the first query is executed. I want to run only that query where the users caret is positioned.

Obviously that example looks easy, but consider more realistic querys used in a real environment, something like:

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3
FROM users
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4);
SELECT * FROM references WHERE status = 1
;
SELECT 
    a.col1
    , a.col2
    , b.col1 
FROM table_a a |                            <--- Here is the caret, run this query
    INNER JOIN table_b b ON b.id_table_a = a.id
WHERE a.id = 5
;
UPDATE table_a SET col1 = 'demo' WHERE id = 3;
-- etc, etc, etc
```

Until now I have the carets position: row & column, and cut the string in two parts: before the caret and after the caret. 
Then I get the substring after last semicolon occurrence at first string, and the substring before de first occurrence at second string.

But i want to know if there are another ways to solve this with more efficiency.

Comment: You're allowing your users to execute arbitrary SQL statements? (Off-topic of the regex question, I know. Just curious.)

Comment: kind of... this tool is for testing only, something like PHPMyAdmin, but for instructional purposes... and some querys are blocked by dbuser permissions

Comment: I think, you shouldn't narrow yourself down with `;` being the delimiter, as it might be necessary to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a regex statement like this:
`/(?<=;)(.*)(?=\|)/`

Comment: I tried that whit this string: `SELECT;UPDATE|query;INSERT; ` and only get the _UPDATE_ part... and expected was _UPDATE query_, but I like this approach.

Comment: Try this one instead:`/(?<=;)(.*?\|.*?)(?=;)/` 

This gets the pipe anywhere in the query, but youll need to replace the pipe after the match to get it out of there. I think there is a way to ignore it. Im not sure off the top of my head, but maybe someone else does. Ill look into it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex or non-regex approach for this.  If your queries are going to contain `|` (pipes) in them then it would be more suitable to nominate a different/unique marker.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rpBTv))

```
$queries="
SELECT col1,col2,col3
FROM users
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4);
SELECT * FROM references WHERE status = 1
;
SELECT 
    a.col1
    , a.col2
    , b.col1 
FROM table_a a |                            <--- Here is the caret, run this query
    INNER JOIN table_b b ON b.id_table_a = a.id
WHERE a.id = 5
;
UPDATE table_a SET col1 = 'demo' WHERE id = 3;
-- etc, etc, etc";

$rtrimmed=substr($queries,0,strpos($queries,'|'));     // remove substr following pipe
$ltrimmed=substr($rtrimmed,strrpos($rtrimmed,';')+1);  // remove substr upto latest semicolon
echo trim($ltrimmed);                                  // remove whitespace on either side

echo "\n---\n";

echo preg_match('~;\s*\K[^;|]*?(?= *\|)~',$queries,$out) ? $out[0] : '';
```

Output:

```
SELECT 
    a.col1
    , a.col2
    , b.col1 
FROM table_a a
---
SELECT 
    a.col1
    , a.col2
    , b.col1 
FROM table_a a
```

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X7e7N8/1)

Pattern Breakdown:

```
~         #pattern delimiter
;\s*      #match semicolon followed by zero or more whitespace characters
\K        #restart the fullstring match (release previous matched characters)
[^;|]*?   #match zero or more (lazily) non-semicolon and non-pipe characters
(?= *\|)  #look ahead for zero or more spaces followed by a pipe (so that the output is trimmed)
~         #pattern delimiter
```